# After Updating FDT, The Splash Screen & Icon Have Disappeared

Tags: eclipse, icons, fdt

When I updated FDT 5.0 -> 5.5, I lost the FDT icon and splash screen. Now it's just a generic Eclipse icon. This happens for every FDT update and not just this one.

What happened?

Answer (score 0):

### The Branding Was Replaced By Another Eclipse Plugin (or Eclipse itself)

Because FDT is Eclipse based, other Eclipse plugins may overwrite some parts of your FDT standalone. Examples include workspace settings and GUI parts of FDT (e.g. the icon and splash screen).

### Changing It Back

To change the icon, replace the icon as you would with any application. To change the spalsh screen, replace the splash.bmp file inside the FDT install directory (OSX users may need to right click on it and go "Shoe Package Contents").

[image]

### Artwork

[image]
[image]